# Fake screen resolution

Tags: javascript, vbscript, screen, resolution, screen-resolution

if I enter to the web site "what-is-my-screen-resolution.com" it's know exactly what is my screen resolution that my computer having.

the thing is that I know that the website using Javascript to get my screen resolution but I don't know where it get that information.
I want to "fake" my screen resolution for software that i'm building and i will be glad if anyone can tell me how can i change only the information that sent to the website and not really my screen resolution.

Thank you

Comment: Then you have to fake the browser environment. What browser do you want to use with software you are building?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript code they are using is:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!--

height = screen.height;
width = screen.width;

res = document.getElementById ('resolutionNumber');
res.innerHTML = width + " X " + height;

if (res == null)
{
    alert ("hello");
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

`screen.height` and `screen.width` give the values of screen resolution.